# Cairngorm Framework V3 Vs Cairngrom framework V2

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm, flex3

I have seen some white papers, Cairngorm V2 is not always good to use for flex framework.
so many flex projects are converted cairngorm 2 to cairngorm 3.

What i guess is what ever cairngorm 3 is developed based on the cairngorm 2 framework.

So why all the projects converted to cairngorm 3 because of some issues in cairngorm 2 while using large flex applications.

thanks,

ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairngorm 3 is NOT a framework.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185149/cairngorm-3-tutorial)

Comment: is cairngorm 2 is a framework?if yes. what i expect is cairngorm 3 is also developed based on the cairngorm2. please calrify me if am wrong.

Comment: Cairngorm 2 is indeed a framework. Cairngorm 3 is not.
It just bad communication from Adobe. 

You will find more info about the subject in this blog article & comments :
http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2010/05/19/how-the-flex-framework-cairngorm-2-died